# How to delete directory from PYTHONPATH in Linux

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath

How to delete directory from PYTHONPATH in Linux. I asked delete permanently folder, no delete with sys.path . This is my new PYTHONPATH

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_adminplus-0.2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_linkedin-2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_debug_toolbar-0.9.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_storages-1.1.8-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_uuidfield-0.4.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.9.7-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg', '/', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

This is my old PYTHONPATH

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_adminplus-0.2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_linkedin-2.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_debug_toolbar-0.9.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_storages-1.1.8-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_uuidfield-0.4.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.9.7-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

difference directory is `'/'`
how to delete this directory permanently ?

Comment: That looks like `sys.path` in Python, not $PYTHONPATH on a *nix commandline.

Comment: Do you want to delete (remove) a directory, or remove it from the variable? I assume the latter, but that depends on how your `PYTHONPATH` is set initially (e.g., through dot-files etc).

Comment: Yes this is shown by the sys.path. But when I did export PYTHONPATH = "$ PYTHONPATH :/ home / my_modules". And then export PYTHONPATH = "". With sys.path saw the difference and then want to remove it, but it was only '\'

Comment: It's unclear what you did exactly: that last command (`export PYTHONPATH = ""`) should almost reset your PYTHONPATH. If it didn't change within the Python shell, you never restarted the Python shell.

Comment: Since you apparently made a simple mistake on the command line in your terminal, just start a new terminal, and you should find your PYTHONPATH as of old.

Comment: To mistake was in that I have not restarted the terminal. Thanks for answering